# What is the difference between APN ssl key production vs sandbox?

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Can someone please ELI5 the difference between APN ssl certificate (sandbox) and APN ssl certificate (sandbox and production).

Answer (score 0):

Apple uses different servers for sending push notifications to development versions and app store versions of the app. The development version is called Sandbox. The iOS maintains persistent connection to the its push servers depending on whether its development version or production version. Based on which certificate your app is signed (Dev or App Store/Ad Hoc) it will create a persistent connection to the respective push server. Since the two servers are different they will need different SSL certificates to establish a secure connection to the server.

For more info refer:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html